# How do I configure the Firebase SDK for the codelab?

Tags: web, cmd, firebase, firebase-hosting

I have followed every instruction as it is in the [codelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/index.html#0) tutorial for the FriendlyChat app to the best of my understanding.

I pasted into the index page the code generated from clicking the <kbd>Add firebase to your web app</kbd> icon in the console.

However, when I run `firebase serve` and load the page at `localhost:5000`, I get an alert telling me I have not configured and imported the Firebase SDK.

How exactly do I configure and import the SDK?

Comment: Did you run `$ bower install firebase`?

Comment: Just tried it now. Then I redid the whole process and i discovered storageBucket hadn't generated a URL in the initialization script. I believe that's where the problem might've been

Comment: Could you paste what you have in the `index.html` ? This message is displayed in this condition: `if (!window.firebase || !(firebase.app instanceof Function) || !window.config) {...`

Comment: Seems you're fine now though but let us know if you are still stuck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to paste the initialization snippet from: 
Firebase Console > Overview > Add Firebase to your web app 
in index.html file in web-start folder.

Answer (score 0):

I found the the above answer a bit unclear but managed to solve it with this method in case it helps anyone:

- Go to the Firebase main page
- Top right (next to your profile image) you'll find 'Go To Console' click on it
- There you'll find your 'FriendlyChat' project, click on it
- On the left, under the Firebase icon, you'll find a gear icon (settings), go there
- Scroll down and you'll find a window with your web apps
- There is a title 'SDK setup and configuration '
- Make sure you include the 'automatic' code in index.html if you haven't already. It will look similar to this:

```
<script src="/__/firebase/8.6.3/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
<script src="/__/firebase/8.6.3/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

<script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
```

- Make sure you include the 'CDN' code in index.html if you haven't already (remember to put it before any firebase script calls). It will look something like this:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.3/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.3/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

<script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "...",
    projectId: "...",
    storageBucket: "...",
    messagingSenderId: "...",
    appId: "...",
    measurementId: "..."
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();
</script>
```

Note: if you didn't include analytics I suppose you shouldn't include the analytic scripts (just copy and paste the code given to you on the website)

This stopped the alert from showing up for me.